# Why two while loops one after the other (not inside the other) in Python don't work?

Tags: python, while-loop, control-flow

I wrote the code below and I was expecting that, when the first loop ends and doesn't return False, the flow would follow to the second while loop. However, the flow skips the second while loop and simply returns True. Why is that? How can I fix this problem, making the flow after the first while loop go to the second while loop?

```
square = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,4],[3,1,2,4],[2,4,4,3]]
# this is an auxiliary function
def getSum(lis):
sum = 0
for e in lis:        
    sum = sum + e
return sum

# here is where the problem is
def check_game(square):
standardSum = getSum(range(1, len(square)+1))    

while square: #this is the first while loop
    row = square.pop()
    print row, 'row', 'sum of row=', getSum(row)
    if standardSum != getSum(row):
        return False
m = 0
while m < len(square): # the second while loop, which the flow skips 
    n = 0
    col = []
    while n < len(square):
        col.append(square[n][m])
        n = n + 1
    print col, 'column'
    if standardSum != getSum(col):
        print standardSum, ' and sum of col =', getSum(col)
        return False            
    m = m + 1
return True
```

Comment: Check the indentation here matches your actual code

Comment: +1 @AramKocharyan: neither of the while loops is actually inside the check_game funciton.

Comment: Yes, I paste wrong, but in my .py file it's with the correct indentation. Thanks, Aram.

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to comment since I'm lying in bed on my phone, but the indentation doesn't look like valid py to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first loop only terminates when there are no more items left in `square`.  After the first loop, `len(square)` will be `0`, so the entry condition for the second loop `m < len(square)` will be `False`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I didn't get it because of the .pop() that reduces the number of elements in square.

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice: Make sure you study the code in [katriealalex' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9657676/279627), which shows how you can write your function in a much more expressive, readable and concise manner.  Try to understand that code, and you might learn a lot about Python!

Answer (score 2):

FYI your code is very (very very very) un-idiomatic Python -- it's written much more like C.

Here's a rewrite which is much more like Python is normally written.

```
square = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,4],[3,1,2,4],[2,4,4,3]]
transpose = lambda i: zip(*i)

def is_magic(square):
    n = len(square)
    s = n*(n+1)/2

    return all(sum(row) == s for row in square) and \
           all(sum(col) == s for col in transpose(square))
```

You may wish to look into `numpy`, which is a Python module for handling matrices. With it:

```
def is_magic(square):
    n = len(square)
    s = n*(n+1)/2

    return all(m.sum(0) == s) and all(m.sum(1) == s)
```

Comment: Well, I's like to understand this code... I've read it 5 times to get an idea... but it's not for me yet. Thank you very much, Katrielalex for this beautiful code!

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice no worries. You should first wrap your head around [list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python). The `transpose` thing is just a trick.

Answer (score 1):

`while square:` will terminate when `square` is empty; it follows that `len(square) == 0`, and thus `m < len(square)` evaluates to false when `m=0`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I didn't get it because of the .pop() that reduces the number of elements in square. Thank you very much, guys!

Answer (score 1):

`square.pop()` returns a row from `square` and *removes the row*, therefore `len(square)` is zero in the second loop.

There is also a built-in function `sum` that does the same thing as your `getSum` function.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I didn't get it because of the .pop() that reduces the number of elements in square.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many times you plan to iterate because you check a length and an increment variable. Use a for loop instead, as it will allow you to initialize the increment and adjust it each loop on the same line. This will avoid issues resulting in infinite loops in the future (even though thisn't the problem here, I consider it relevant to point out).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid your error by replacing your first while with this:

```
for row in square:
  print row, 'row', 'sum of row=', getSum(row)
  if standardSum != getSum(row):
     return False
```